# PHP e-commerce order split to sellers Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, e-commerce, laravel-5.3

I'm currently building a little webshop using Laravel 5.3, where users can register and add products to sell. Another user can then search for products, putt them in the shopping cart and buy those. Then I save this order information into the db (as 2 tables), `order` (containing the id (of the order), the user_id (who bought it), and the total paid amount) and then theres `order_items` (containing the id, the relating order id and the product id).

Now I want to give the seller as well as the buyer the possibility to view the past orders. Now comes the clue: Showing this to the buyer is as easy as could be, because I just need to check for the user id in the `orders`table and get those. But seller is not that easy, after I thought about, because the seller should also see "his" orders, so the orders from buyers, that contain one or more of his products, BUT: he should only see the part of the order with his products and not the products the buyer propably bought from somebody else. I think you know what I mean?

Is there any way to solve this "easily" or a best practice how this is done? 
Basically I could just create two subtables, called `sub_orders` and `sub_order_items` or something and then create a `sub_order` for every seller (creating this right after creating the order), but this is not too easy to implement (I guess) and maybe there's a better way I'm not thinking of yet.

Are there any ideas?

Those are all relevant models:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OrderItem extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_items';

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**Edit**: This is what I got so far:

```
$orders = Order::whereHas('orderItems.product', function ($query) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id);
        })->get();

        return view('order.list',['orders'=>$orders]);
```

So this lists all orders that contain at least one product from the seller. When I know (in that view `order.list`) click on one order I can see all the products of the order, but I just want to see those who are from this seller. 
This is how I show a single order:

```
public function viewOrder($orderId){
        $order = Order::find($orderId);
        return view('order.view',['order'=>$order]);
    }
```

How can I now only show relevant products of the order and the sum of those relevant products only?

Comment: Don't you have a ```seller_id``` or something alike in the ```products``` table? If you do (and I'm guessing you do), it should be easy. You will have to show products (items) for order ```WHERE``` the ```seller_id``` is the logged in seller's ```id```.

Comment: @IlkerMutlu yes i do have this id in the products table, but i need to get the order, not the product...

Comment: I know. Filter the orders which have a product belonging to that specific seller. See [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) for a hint. ;)

Comment: @IlkerMutlu Thanks for that hint, but can you give me an example how I could this in my case? I'm partially using this already (for shopping cart relation to shopping cart items as well as orders with order_items) but I still didn't really get this...what do I have to change in my model and how can I then call these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you named your Models, but here's the idea. Something like:

```
// get the logged in seller and set it to $seller

$orders = Order::whereHas('orderItems.product', function ($query) {
    $query->where('seller_id', '=', $seller->id);
})->get();

// will get you orders that have products by this seller
```

From that point on, you can filter what you want to show (exclude products in the order by different sellers, etc.)

Comment: I'm getting `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Product()`, what do i need to write here? the db table name? the model name?

Comment: do I need to change something in my model too? like `Order->hasMany('products')` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, the answer assumes you have relationships already defined. See [Laravel Defining Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

Comment: Is there a way to define more then one relationships? Because I already have `return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');`, how can I also add the products in there?

Comment: You can define as many as you like. How about you post some code about those models we are talking about?

Comment: See the answer update where we use dot notation to create a somewhat nested whereHas filter.

Comment: Let's move to chat, but I'll be driving for a while so expect some latency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127942/discussion-between-ilker-mutlu-and-nameless).

Comment: I got it now, so now I only see orders that contain at least one item from this seller. Now the question is: How can I then filter out only the products of the seller and calc the total sum? Notice the changes I made on the question to know how i show orders

Comment: the problem is that I would have to pass changed orders to the view showing a specific order, at least seems so...

Comment: Let's move to chat.